# Translation of "full of surprises"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How would you translate

> The world is full of surprises.

Would it be

> (a) Die Welt ist voll Überraschungen.

or

> (b) Die Welt ist voll von Überraschungen.

or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can translate it both ways if you correct some minor mistakes, see the following.

> Die Welt ist voller Überraschungen.

> Die Welt ist voll von Überraschungen.

Grammatically, the first sentence uses genitive case, the second one dative case.

Comment: At least to me the former sounds more idiomatic.